# Plugin system in SailsJS application

Tags: node.js, plugins, sails.js

I'm working on a [NodeJS application](https://github.com/ciaa-cnam/STOFMA), using SailsJS, and I want to implement (or use if exists) a system to manage plugins. By "plugin", I mean a module that I could add in a "plugins" directory.

Is someone has ever tried to do something like that ?

Comment: Why not doing something like `require('./plugins/your_module.js')` https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: Is there a reason for not using [hooks](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks) or [services](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/api/services)?

Comment: I think the best way to extend your sails app is to create custom generators https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/generators/custom-generators  or hooks like @AlexisN-o says... but this is using the CLI not a drop-in like Wordpress plugin